# How to create popover on fly?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a list of rows, they are having IDs, e.g. #car1, #car2, #car3
I need to generate dynamic popover, show it in right of div, and close then by timeout.
I have probelms with creation.

```
var pop = $().popover({
    selector: '#car1',
    title: 'foo',
    content: 'bar',
    container: 'body'
});

pop.popover('show');
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: @putvande like in tag twitter-bootstrap.js i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify any selector actually, use this instead:

```
var pop = $('#car1').popover({
    title: 'foo',
    content: 'bar',
    container: 'body'
});
```

Comment: and still use selector option to enable delegation if unique element #car1 is removed/readded to the DOM. I guess it is how OP wish it to work. And i hope OP is using unique IDs

Comment: Looks like selector is required. I will change my code. Thanks for clarifying.